# TFS 2017 - NuGet Publisher step during a build fails with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: tfs, build, nuget

I have a build definition that includes steps to package and publish a NuGet package to an internal feed. That internal feed resides on the same TFS server.

- This is on prem
- TFS 2017 15.105.25910.0
- Permissions for the feed are:
- OWNERS:

  - [My account]
  - [Collection]\Project Collection Administrators
- Contributors

  - Project Collection Build Service(TEAM FOUNDATION)
- Readers

  - [Collection]\Project Collection Valid Users

The NuGet package step works fine, but the NuGet publish step fails with the following error:

```
Unable to load the service index for source https://[server]/[collection]/_packaging/Feed/nuget/v3/index.json. 
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

I put in a Powershell script early in the build definition to determine the exact account being used during the build process, and it indicated **Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)**, which has permission to contribute to the feed.

Here are the contents of the Nuget.Config file at `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\NuGet>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

What other information would be useful to help me diagnose with issue?

Comment: Under the Security tab for my collection, and then under TFS groups, in the group Security Service Group I have listed the following members:[TEAM FOUNDATION], Build\{guid}, Build {Different Guid}. It seems like instead of a Guid it should resolve to the username? Is something perhaps broken here?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the default **access level** was set to “**Stakeholder**” in your TFS server.

If so, manually add the *TFS Service account/ Project Collection Build Service* explicitly to the **Advanced** group and try to run the build again. For more details please refer this similar issue: [TFS 2017 NuGet publisher task fails with 401 - Unauthorized exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/12/06/tfs-2017-nuget-publisher-task-fails-with-401-unauthorized-exception/)

Comment: According to my TFS server, "Advanced access level has been deprecated. Test Manager extension includes all testing capabilities previously part of the advanced access level." Should I add the user to the VS Enterprise Access Level instead?

Comment: Also, my default access level is set to Basic, not Stakeholder.

Comment: @Dbloom Yes,  seems you are using TFS2017 update2. For this version, use the VS Enterprise access level if you have active Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers , otherwise you could still use advanced access. Add the  **TFS Service account/ Project Collection Build Service**   explicitly  to the  VS Enterprise Access Level and trigger the build again to see if the issue solved.

Comment: Actually we were using TFS 2017 RTM. Just this morning however we did upgrade to TFS 2017 Update 2. I will try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: @Dbloom — How'd it go? Were you able to get past this?

Comment: I'm getting the same 401 error, even after making the recommended configurations. I've: 1) Set Basic as the default Access Level, 2) Added the TFS Service account (a domain account) to the VS Enterprise access level, 3) Added the TFS Service account to the Project Collection Build Service Accounts group, 4) Added the TFS Service account to Package Management under Users, and 5) Restarted all TFS-related services. Have I missed anything? I'm running 2017.2.

Comment: I changed my NuGet version from v4.0.0 back to the default v3.3.0 in the Build Step, and the Build/Publish ran successfully. I found that NuGet v3.5.0 fails as well. What to make of this?

Comment: It turned out we had two collections on this TFS server, and I was using the build account from the wrong collection.

Comment: @Dbloom — Funny... I've never done anything like that ;-) BTW I didn't see your comment until just now, and then only by chance. When you're addressing someone in the comment thread (except for the person who posted the thread's answer) you have to include his SO username prefaced with an @ symbol. This way your comment will make it to his inbox.

Comment: FYI I've entered a problem report [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/150505/tfs-nuget-publisher-step-fails-with-401-on-newer-v.html).

Comment: It turns out that the failure was caused by Basic Authentication being enabled in IIS. See my answer below. Once I disabled it, I was able to use the latest version of NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Basic Authentication enabled in IIS for the `tfs` website? This was the cause of the problem for my TFS 2017.2 instance. Once I disabled it, the build went through successfully.

> "TFS expects IIS level basic auth setting to be Off."

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110312/tfs2017-build-nuget-unable-to-restore-package-from.html