# Can't paste text at a TFX-CLI console (NPM)

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I'm unable to paste text at CLI prompts when running [`tfx-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tfx-cli).

I've just installed Node v8.9.1 LTS. Unfortunately, the `tfx-cli` install hung the first time through. I pressed `Ctrl+C` to cancel it, ran it again, and the second time it completed. (In the text that flashed across my screen during the second run, I believe I saw something about 'failed' and 'rollback.')

I don't know whether the initial failure is contributing to my problem.

When I run `tfx login`, I get this prompt first:

`> Service URL:`

I can type at this prompt, but I can't paste. Once I type the URL and press `Enter` I get this:

`> Personal access token:`

I can neither paste nor type at this prompt (or at least the cursor doesn't advance when I type). The only keys that seem to work here are `Enter` and `Ctrl+C`. Pressing `Enter` without typing anything results in this:

`error:   Invalid input for Personal access token:`

Pressing `Enter` after typing a few random characters sends no output to the console and simply dumps me back at the `C:\>` prompt.

How to fix this? How can one determine whether it's a Node problem or a `tfx-cli` problem? I suspect the latter but I'm not sure.

**--EDIT--**

Are others able to paste text at these prompts?

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my side with Node v8.9.1 LTS installed. Everything works correctly.

Make sure you have **activated the command line window** before pasting the text.

For `Personal access token` or password, **it's implicit (non-visible)** in the command line. The token strings will not show there when pasting the PAT/password. But it works if you enter the correct token.

So, just make sure you activated the cmd window before paste action:

1. Copy PAT/password (*Sometimes you need to try this several times to make sure the strings are copied*)
2. Activate the command line window (*click within the window to active
   it*)
3. Paste the PAT/password (*It's implicit, just make sure you pasted the
   correct token* )
4. Enter

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems related to the OS or permission. Whatever, you can try **running the cmd as Administrator**, then check whether you can copy and paste now.

Besides, you can also try to enable "QuickEdit Mode" for CMD console. ( Right-click on the title-bar of your cmd window. --> [Properties] - Options - check "QuickEdit Mode"

Also try the ways mentioned in this article: [How to Enable CTRL+C / Ctrl+V for Pasting in the Windows Command Prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25590/how-to-enable-ctrlv-for-pasting-in-the-windows-command-prompt/)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've activated the CLI window. But thank you. Note in my original description that upon pasting and pressing Enter, I get the same result as when I press Enter without pasting: `error: Invalid input for Personal access token:`. And then when I type random characters and press Enter, I get dumped back at the command line. Also—I installed Node/TFX on another workstation and the same thing happened. TFX installation hung midway, it was successful the 2nd time, and I can't paste my PAT. ANYWAY... I was able to get in using Basic Authentication and typing my credentials.

Comment: @InteXX When you keep the PAT as empty, it will display the error message: `error: Invalid input for Personal access token` ,So as I said above make sure you have copied and pasted the correct token. Type random characters, the characters are considered as the token.  Press **Enter**  it get dumped back at the command line is the expected behavior. It will not confirm whether the toke is correct or not at this step. As you can see from the screenshot above, paste text and the tfx cli all working on my side.

Comment: This sounds great; I wish I could get it working on my side. No matter what I try, pasting the token and pressing Enter results in `error: Invalid input for Personal access token`. Did your install go well? Could this be related to the twice-failed-on-two-machines installation hang I experienced? FYI I tried typing my PAT just now, character by character, and I was able to authenticate. It just won't paste. (I pasted it into TextPad to verify that it was on the clipboard.)

Comment: @InteXX I installed the Node.js and tfx-cli on win2016 server OS without any error in one time. Seems it's the OS or CMD issue on your side. Just make sure you have activated the CLI window, If that still not work, you can try other consoles, eg : PowerShell, in powershell console, right click action will paste the text by default.

Comment: Same thing with PowerShell. It won't accept a paste. This is a tricky one, isn't it?

Comment: @InteXX Seems related to the OS or permission. Whatever, you can try running the cmd as Administrator, then check whether you can copy and paste now. See the updated answer.

Comment: That's what I thought too, which is why I installed on a different OS with different permissions. Same result. I also already have `Ctrl` key combinations enabled for the Command Window. But the AutoHotkey idea is new—and it looks like it just might work. Thanks for that.

Comment: Andy, thanks for checking in. I'm unable to try AutHotKey due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47315706/722393). That's OK, though, because I only wanted CLI access to accomplish one thing: deletion of a custom build task. I ended up getting that via the REST API, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293505/722393). Appreciate all your help. Keep up the good work.