# Can't uninstall a package

Tags: npm

I'm getting this error text when attempting to uninstall `tfx-cli`:

```
C:\Users\Admin>npm uninstall tfx-cli
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Admin\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Admin\package.json'
npm WARN Admin No description
npm WARN Admin No repository field.
npm WARN Admin No README data
npm WARN Admin No license field.

up to date in 0.14s
```

I'm trying to uninstall due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47233884/722393), so I can attempt another reinstall.

The file `C:\Users\Admin\package.json` doesn't exist, but `C:\Users\Admin\package-lock.json` does. It contains a single line of text:

> {
>     "lockfileVersion": 1
>   }

How to get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` by default looks for the package in local folder. You need to use `-g` option if you want to install/uninstall globally.

```
npm uninstall -g tfx-cli
```